# What does "genki desu" mean in Japanese?

Tags: conversations

I know it is used to respond to someone or something, but i don't get the meaning of it?

Comment: That is a "Japanese" phrase that is used way more often by Japanese-learners than by us native speakers.

Comment: https://lmgtfy.com/?q=genki%20desu&s=g

Answer (score 2):

The expression 元気{げんき}です can for instance be the answer in:

> —How are you?
>
> —I’m fine.

The word *genki* (元気 or げんき) means that you are full of energy (vigour), healthy, in a good mood et cetera. It may also be used in other situations. Note that there is an element of healthiness, wellbeing or alertness involved in this expression.

Answer (score 0):

The expression "genki desu" 元気（げんき）です is usually used to answer the question "o genki desu ka" お元気（げんき）ですか

Just as Kess answered, the question and answer is almost the same as

> -How are you?
>
> -I am fine.

But normally, when someone (especially those who are senior) asks
"o genki desu ka" お元気（げんき）ですか？ Japanese would choose to answer with “おかけさまで、元気です” "o ka ge sa ma de, genki desu" to show their politeness. And "o ka ge sa ma de" means "thanks to you".